# Solving simple transfer function

Tags: transfer-function

I was hoping that you can help me understand how to find poles and zeros in this transfer function.

$$
H(s)=\frac{1}{(s-s_{\alpha1})(s-s_{\alpha2})}
$$

I know that this function does not have any zeros, because of the 1.

From the solutions I can see that the poles are $s_{\alpha1}=-1+j$ and $s_{\alpha2}=-1-j$ and to tell you the truth, I have no idea how to get solution for the poles.

I tried to solve it using quadratic equation, but the only thing I get is a big mess.

Thanks!!

Comment: The poles simply are $s_{\alpha1}$ and $s_{\alpha2}$. That's it, you obviously can't get numerical values from this general transfer function. The transfer function also has a double zero at infinity.

Comment: Then this assingment is incomplete, because i cant find any values that are given to the sα1 and sα2

Comment: If the only thing you have is $H(s)$ then you can't do more than I told you. No figure, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Because $s-s_{\alpha1} = 0 $ and $s-s_{\alpha2} = 0 $ so poles: $s_1,s_2 = s_{\alpha1},s_{\alpha2} $ 
What numerical values you have for $s_{\alpha1},s_{\alpha2} $ are the What numerical values you are looking for.